kubectl edit rolls back to previous configuration automatically?
After running kubectl edit and editing a DaemonSet, after a while, the DaemonSet goes back to its previous configuration. What can be the reason for that?
I've edited some environment variables of the DaemonSet, as well as its resource limits, and after 30 minutes, I've noticed that kubernetes destroyed all the pods of the DS and created new ones.
kubectl describe just says that pods X Y and Z were destroyed, and pods A B and C were created, nothing more.

That can happen if something else (maybe a continuous-deployment system?) is trying to also manage the DaemonSet.  I'd use kubectl edit sparingly, since there's no record of what changes you've actually made this way; prefer using something that can be tracked in source control.
